# convert png image to svg, client base or server base?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, svg, png

I want to convert a png image to svg in my website to edit this image.

- Is it better implement this converter in backend side(with php) or in client side(with javascript)?
- How can i Implement it?(whether javascript or php) is there any library to help me?

I would be appreciated if you comparison this two type of implement(backend and client side)
thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript isn't built to process images like that. You'll have to do this server-side.

Comment: There is no good tool (server side too) to do that. Impossible to create vector from normal image

Comment: I completely overlooked the image -> vector image conversion. Yea, that's going to be a problem.

Comment: mainly I want to resize the png image which user uploaded, How can I do it ? what is best practice for this problem? I though I can convert it to svg then resize and edit image

Comment: Set the size of the image to be the size you want it to display as.

Comment: if I use this method the quality of image might be going to bad and the pixel may be showed.I want to change this size without any effect to this quality.

Comment: so you are trying to move from rasterized space into vector space... thats equal to asking for flying bicycles

Comment: Can you describe what your original problem is?  You seem to be asking how to achieve the solution you have already come up with.  However, I suspect that the correct solution to your problem is different from what you think it is.